# creating a route for server to access clients

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I have a problem what I believe is a routing issue but I cannot solve it. Current setup on my company is like this [image: schema]

In current setup,

- every client can access to internet using CLIENT => MAIN => MODEM
- every client can access to WEB using CLIENT => MAIN => MODEM => WEB
- WEB cannot access behind MAIN

now, for one specific case, our WEB server needs to access one of the clients, say CLIENT 1. I could not manage to create such route. could someone please explain me how to accomplish such task and describe me how.

I tried to create a route on WEB like this

```
route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 192.168.2.200
```

and tried to create another rule on MAIN using RRAS. It did not work and I deleted it and all clients are disconnected from internet. only a reboot recovered. problem is I don't remember the route added.

servers are Windows 2008 R2, clients are Windows 7

any help is appreciated

UPDATE 1: Added route tables

[image: route tables]

Comment: Does MAIN perform NAT on the 10.0.0.0 subnet?

Comment: It seems NAT is enabled on RRAS on internet interface

Comment: Please share the routing tables on the involved systems and which systems do NAT.

Comment: Is it a specific service `Web` need to access at `client`? Is that requirement fixed or keep changing?

Comment: at the moment only one service is required (MS DTC), but it may change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If WEB has the modem as default gateway, you have to add on the modem a route pointing subnet `10.0.0.0` to MAIN. From MAIN, since the clients are direct connected, you don't need any additional route.

Otherwise, if WEB has MAIN as default gateway, you may have a firewall problem, and not a routing issue.

Comment: I added a route to WEB to route traffic to `10.0.0.0` over `192.168.2.200`. Then I pinged `10.0.0.2` and ping fails on `192.168.2.200`

Comment: Have you tried `tracert`? Do you have netmonitor or wireshark installed on MAIN?

Comment: tracert shows timeout error after 192.168.2.200. that's after I created the route. no, neither  netmonitor, not wireshark is installed, but I can install if it will not disconnect anyone.

Comment: it will disconnect everyone. But, you already know that your routing is working fine. Now it's just a matter of firewall rules on your windows server.

Comment: I turned down the firewall on both MAIN and CLIENT1 for a few seconds and it sill gives me timeouts.

Comment: Have you checked if RRAS is treating the routing as it should?

Comment: You don't need the route to `10.0.0.101` to be added to MAIN. And if you have the route added to your modem, you don't need it on WEB

Comment: Ok. What must I do to check how RRAS is treating the route? BTW, I get that route should be created on WEB, but I do not want other machines connected to MODEM to access internal network.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable NAT on the RRAS then, I have never used it but assuming it's semi competent you should be able to selectively NAT based on destination, try to tweak NAT so it doesn't nat traffic destined to 192.168.2.0/24